# Remove focus and hover AntD Buttons

Tags: reactjs, button, antd

Antd buttons have a weird behavior where the text and border becomes blue ... even when I set the `:focus` and `:hover` to `color: 'black'`.

Is there any way to have hover events none similar to `pointer-events: none` ?

When I inspect element, it shows `ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false"` when focused.

Answer (score 1):

There is a by default class applied in Antd button (ant-btn) simply you need to give className to your button and style in global CSS

`.adjust_button_hover_drawer.ant-btn:hover { border-color: white !important; }`